# In Sequelize how do you correctly use the set method after a record is created using .then()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Using sequelize how do you correctly use the set method in this case, or is there another way to achieve this: When a `contact` is created they `belongTo` an `org` and an `org` `hasMany` `contact`(s). When creating the `contact`, if `org_name` is added in the create method, the field can not be created as there is a case where the `org` may not exist, in that event the `org` is created. After the `org` exists using `.then()`, how do you set the `org_name` to the `org_name` that was just created (or that already exists in the `orgs` model) on the newly created `contact`? Below is the attempt (with a comment for the line not working):

```
const models = require('../models');

exports.createContact = (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    Promise.all([
        models.contacts.create({
            first_name: body.first_name,
            last_name: body.last_name,
        }),
        models.phones.create({
            phone_id: body.phone_id
        }),
        models.emails.create({
            email_id: body.email_id
        })
    ])
    .then(([contacts, orgs, phones, emails]) => {
        console.log(contacts)
        console.log(orgs.org_name) // does return the correct `org_name` from the `orgs` model
        return Promise.all([
            contacts.setOrgs(orgs.org_name), // this does not work
            models.contact_phone.create({
                contact_id: contacts.contact_id, 
                phone_id: phones.phone_id
            }),
            models.contact_email.create({
                contact_id: contacts.contact_id, 
                email_id: emails.email_id
            })
        ])
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
};
```

Comment: please clarify more . i didn't get your point

Comment: Is the `org_name` field a primary key of `orgs`?

Comment: @Anatoly yes `org_name` is the primary key of `orgs`

Comment: Promise.all ia called with 3 arguments while `then(([contacts, orgs, phones, emails])` has 4 elements? Did you miss `orgs.create`? Also `contacts.setOrgs(orgs.org_name)` accepts an array of id'. If you wish to set a single id call `setOrg(orgs.org_name)`